# ASP.NET MVC connect buttons to methods in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two buttons in my view and I want to add some information to my database when user click each of these two buttons.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="btn-group" style="text-align: center">
        <h2>
            <font color="gray">Please Choose your Department</font></h2>
        <div class="btn-toolbar pagination-centered">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button id="SARU" class="btn btn-inverse btn-large">
                    SARU</button>
                <div class="span1">
                    <button id="AN" class="btn btn-inverse :hover btn-large">
                        AN</button>
                </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#SARU').click(function () {
            UserController.AddGroupSARU();
        });

        $('#AN').click(function () {
            UserController.AddGroupAN();
        });
     </script>    
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the AddGroupSARU and AddGroupAN methods are in Usercontroller . how should I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jquery ajax to make a call to the action method. You can use the `$.post` method.

```
$(function(){

    $('#SARU').click(function () {

        $.post("@Url.Action("AddGroupSARU","User")");
    });
});
```

The `Url.Action` helper method will resolve the proper path to the action method and render it. If you look at the View source of the page you will see the js code like

```
$(function(){

    $('#SARU').click(function () {

       $.post("User/AddGroupSARU");
    });
});
```

Decorate your action method with `[HttpPost]` attribute as well. It is a good idea to keep your data updation/insertion/**DELETION** operations in a HttpPost action method so that boats/search engine won't destroy your data.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddGroupSARU()
{
  // do something and return something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use Jquery and ajax. i try to use Razor to connect button to methods in controller
like this..

```
<input style="width:100px;" type="button" title="EditHotelDetail" value="EditDetails"  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Hotel")'" />
```

"Edit" is name of your methods
"Hotel" is name of your controller